# Clustergrammer getting negative values for rects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to pull up and example clustergrammer using the Clusergrammer JS developed here: http://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/clustergrammer_js.html#example-pages

I've pulled in the relevant code and am loading in an already calculated JSON. According to the workflow online this is all I should need to do. Unfortunately, I'm getting d3 errors during its build. More specifically, rect attribute height is getting a negative value which is not valid.

Here is the js and the html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/MaayanLab/clustergrammer/master/clustergrammer.js"></script> 
<!--<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="clustergram.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clusterCtrl">
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>



</html>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('clusterCtrl', function($scope) {

//functions
$scope.initialize = initialize;
$scope.build = build;

//variables
$scope.gridSize = 120;

function build() {;
  var cgm = Clustergrammer($scope.args);
}

function initialize() {
    $scope.build();
}

$scope.data = {"cat_colors": {"col": {"cat-0": {"Category: two": "#ffbb78"}, "cat-1": {"Gender: Male": "#ff7f0e"}}, "row": {"cat-0": {"Gene Type: Interesting": "#393b79", "Gene Type: Not Interesting": "#eee"}}}, "col_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 0, "cat_1_index": 0, "clust": 1, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Cell Line: H1650", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 1}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 1, "cat_1_index": 1, "clust": 0, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Cell Line: H23", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 2, "cat_1_index": 2, "clust": 2, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Cell Line: CAL-12T", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 2}], "links": [], "mat": [[-0.792803571, 0.527687127, 0.000622536], [0.17762054, -0.016061488999999998, 5.422113832999999], [-0.6978761509999999, -0.555610265, -0.36049755899999997], [0.8505465179999999, -0.263279907, 0.179253031]], "row_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Gene Type: Interesting", "cat_0_index": 0, "clust": 0, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 4, "name": "Gene: CDK4", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 2}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 1, "clust": 2, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Gene: LMTK3", "rank": 3, "rankvar": 3}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 2, "clust": 1, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Gene: LRRK2", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 3, "clust": 3, "group": [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Gene: UHMK1", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 1}], "views": [{"N_row_sum": "all", "dist": "cos", "nodes": {"col_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 0, "cat_1_index": 0, "clust": 1, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Cell Line: H1650", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 1}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 1, "cat_1_index": 1, "clust": 0, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Cell Line: H23", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 2, "cat_1_index": 2, "clust": 2, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Cell Line: CAL-12T", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 2}], "row_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Gene Type: Interesting", "cat_0_index": 0, "clust": 0, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 4, "name": "Gene: CDK4", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 2}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 1, "clust": 2, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Gene: LMTK3", "rank": 3, "rankvar": 3}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 2, "clust": 1, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Gene: LRRK2", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 3, "clust": 3, "group": [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Gene: UHMK1", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 1}]}}, {"N_row_var": "all", "dist": "cos", "nodes": {"col_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 0, "cat_1_index": 0, "clust": 1, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Cell Line: H1650", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 1}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 1, "cat_1_index": 1, "clust": 0, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Cell Line: H23", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Category: two", "cat-1": "Gender: Male", "cat_0_index": 2, "cat_1_index": 2, "clust": 2, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Cell Line: CAL-12T", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 2}], "row_nodes": [{"cat-0": "Gene Type: Interesting", "cat_0_index": 0, "clust": 0, "group": [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 4, "name": "Gene: CDK4", "rank": 1, "rankvar": 2}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 1, "clust": 2, "group": [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 3, "name": "Gene: LMTK3", "rank": 3, "rankvar": 3}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 2, "clust": 1, "group": [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 2, "name": "Gene: LRRK2", "rank": 0, "rankvar": 0}, {"cat-0": "Gene Type: Not Interesting", "cat_0_index": 3, "clust": 3, "group": [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "ini": 1, "name": "Gene: UHMK1", "rank": 2, "rankvar": 1}]}}]};



$scope.args = {
  'root': '#container',
  'network_data': $scope.data
};



$scope.initialize();

});
```

Comment: Change your tag from `angular` to `angularjs`, those are two different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I'm the primary developer of Clustergrammer. I have not used Angular, but I think your error might be caused by not defining a size for your container div `#container`. Try setting the height and width of this to 500px and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

There are three required properties for the Visualization-JSON: row_nodes, col_nodes, and mat (links can be used in place of mat and will continue to be supported, but the default format will use mat). Each of these properties is an array of objects and these objects are discussed below.
Example:

```
  var data = {
                          "row_nodes":[...],
                          "col_nodes":[...],
                          "mat": [...]
                        }
```